# Drupal commerce checkout page is not redirecting

Tags: 7, commerce

I am working on e-commerce website and using [Drupal commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) module. I have created several products and allow `authenticated` user to view `checkout` page. Everything was working fine and order was created in site.

Now, I have implemented shipping functionality using [Commerce UPS](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_ups) module. I have also installed [commerce physical](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_physical) module and created `weight` and `dimension` field with content type and update each `product` with `weight` and `dimension` field.

I have also configured `commerce ups` module in admin with correct `username`, `password` and `access key`.

Now, the problem is that when I am adding address in `checkout` page and submitting the `form`, its not redirecting to next step (`shipping service`).

I have checked in google and drupal.org and issue queue of module but did not find any solution.

I have no idea that I am facing this issue due to some wrong configuration of module or this is issue with `shipping` or `commerce ups` module.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

After perform R&D, I found that `$form_state` contains `$form_state['rebuild'] => TRUE` in `commerce_checkout_form_validate()` function, but I am not getting any `error` in `form`.

Please suggest, if you have any solution.

Comment: Can you put the shipping pane on the checkout page, instead of its own page?

Comment: I have also tried the same and its showing `shipping service` but not redirecting to next step `review` when submitting the form.